# How can I set up my firebase rules so only content-owners have read and write to their data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have checked the documentation but I am not sure how to apply that rule to my specific data structure, please check how my data is organized and provide me the rules as it is supposed to go.

I am using realtime Database, in my app code I write and read base on the user ID, but firebase keeps telling I should change my rules.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the rules in the documentation on [content-owner only access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access) to your structure would take:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Expenses": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        // Allow only authenticated content owners access to their data
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```